# HTTP Date Format in Blackberry

Tags: datetime, blackberry, java-me

I need HTTP date format in blackberry. Example:

> Sat, 13 Apr 2013 06:06:13 GMT

I have Implemented that. here is my code of Date Util Class:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale;
import net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateUtils {

       private static SimpleDateFormat _df;

       public static String getDate()
       {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime( new Date() );

          int year = cal.get( Calendar.YEAR );
          int month = cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1;
          int day = cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

          return "" + year
                 + "-" + month
                 + "-" + day;
       }


       public static String getHttpDate()
       {
          return getHttpDate( new Date() );
       }

       public static String getHttpDate( long timestamp )
       {
          return getHttpDate( new Date( timestamp ) );
       }

       public static String getHttpDate( Date date )
       {
          return _df.format( date );
       }

       public static String getTime()
       {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime( new Date() );

          int hours = cal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
          // use 24 hour clock
          int minutes = cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
          int seconds = cal.get( Calendar.SECOND );
          int milli = cal.get( Calendar.MILLISECOND );

          return formatTime( hours, minutes, seconds, milli );
       }

       public static String getTimestamp()
       {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime( new Date() );

          int year = cal.get( Calendar.YEAR );
          int month = cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1;
          int day = cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
          int hours = cal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
          // use 24 hour clock
          int minutes = cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
          int seconds = cal.get( Calendar.SECOND );
          int milli = cal.get( Calendar.MILLISECOND );

          return "" + year
                 + "-" + month
                 + "-" + day
                 + "_" + formatTime( hours, minutes, seconds, milli );
       }

       private static String formatTime( int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milli )
       {
          StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
          buf.append( "" + hours );

          buf.append( "." );

          if( minutes < 10 )
             buf.append( "0" + minutes );
          else
             buf.append( "" + minutes );

          buf.append( "." );

          if( seconds < 10 )
             buf.append( "0" + seconds );
          else
             buf.append( "" + seconds );

          buf.append( "-" );

          if( milli < 10 )
             buf.append( "00" + milli );
          else if( milli < 100 )
             buf.append( "0" + milli );
          else
             buf.append( "" + milli );

          return buf.toString();
       }

       static
       {
          _df = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

       }
}
```

And I am using this class like this:

```
private String getDate()
{       
    String date= DateUtils.getHttpDate(new Date());
    if(date.trim().length()!=("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").length())
        date = date.substring(0, ("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").length());
    System.out.println("Date is >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+date);
    return date;
}
```

The issue which i am facing is that, Its working on simulator of OS 5 and Os 7.
But, not on OS 6 simulator.
On torch 9800 simulator, I am getting

> Sat, 13 Apr 2013 11:33:19 Asi

When, I checked on device,facing same issue.
Please help, i need this urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleDateFormat` will convert your `Date` object to a `Calendar` object which will have its timezone as device's default timezone

The string that you are getting is actually something like `Sat, 13 Apr 2013 11:33:19 Asia/xxxx` where xxxx is some place depending on your country of residence in asia. You are then cutting it down to `Sat, 13 Apr 2013 11:33:19 Asi`

If you want to get the data in GMT, you need to pass the Calendar object with correct timezone.

```
public static String getHttpDate( Date date )
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.setTime(date);
    return _df.format(cal);
}
```

PS: The above code only works on BlackBerry but not on Java SE.